# Routes are not working after publishing my React Web App to Apache production server

Tags: reactjs, apache, web, routes, production

I was execute this command:

```
$ npm run-script build
```

The initial page works well, but any link with routes (for example "login") doesn't work.

How I can change the script "build" or correct that?

Any ideas?

Comment: try `npm run build`

Comment: Thanks... Work better then run-script in Ubuntu, but don't solve the problem.  :(

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a problem with your build.

I guess you are using React Routers BrowserRouter? If so, your React Application is handling the routing. That means that your Apache config has to be configured to always respond with your builds index.html for whatever url is requested.

Check out this example config: https://gist.github.com/alexsasharegan/173878f9d67055bfef63449fa7136042

Hope that helps